# In the hts package, why does the gts function hard code 2-combinations when creating a group structure?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

In the `hts` package, grouped time series structures are created using `gts`. That function calls another function named, `CreateGmat`, where a 2-combination

```
cn <- combn(1L:total.len, 2)
```

is calculated and used to guide the construction of the group structure which is represented by a "g-matrix". For smaller structures with fewer categories, using only a 2-combination to create the structure makes intuitive sense, but I wondering if this should always be the case.

I haven't gone through *all* the code, yet, but my intuition is the G-matrix determines the S-matrix which affects the Reconciliation matrix which affects the forecasts that are calculated using the Optimal Combination method.

Unless my understanding of how the reconciliation process occurs is wrong, how the G-matrix is formulated is at least somewhat important to how the forecasts are calculated. For large structures with many categories, would including combinations greater than two affect the forecasts in any significantly positive way? Is there a statistical or experimental reason for using only a 2-combination?

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me, and also to @earo-wang, the primary author of the package being discussed.

Comment: This question completely makes sense to me. I'm also the maintainer of the hts package, which is addressed in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding about G-matrix is absolutely correct. If there are more than 3 grouping variables, we need to create a G-matrix with 2-way and 3-way interactions. I had some code to automate more than 3-way combinations for a project last year, but never ended up putting it to the **hts** package.

```
nvars <- length(chr_key)
possible_len <- seq_len(nvars - 1)
list_comb <- lapply(possible_len, function(x) combn(seq_len(nvars), x,
  simplify = FALSE))
cs_comb <- c(0, cumsum(choose(nvars, possible_len)))
len_comb <- cs_comb[nvars]
```